# Store A Specific Line Of An Application's Output in a Variable

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm using ImageMagick Identify utility to get an image information, here is the code which use it in VBScript:

```
Dim SH
Set SH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
SH.Run ".\identify.exe -verbose D:\Scans\1.jpg"
```

It will launch identify.exe and will show information of jpg in a console window and it will close! The output on console window has so many lines, I want to store line 5 for example in a variable in VBScript, just imagine line 5 is "Resolution 72DPI" and I want to store it in ResDPI in vbscript so that I an use it for future purposes.

```
Dim SH,strOut
Set SH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
SH.Run ".\identify.exe -verbose D:\Scans\1.jpg"
strOut = identify.exe output Line 5
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. Try redirecting the output to a file that you can later parse:

   ```
   sh.Run ".\identify.exe -verbose D:\Scans\1.jpg >c:\out.txt"
   ```
2. Use Exec() instead of Run(). With Exec() you can read the StdOutput and StdError streams of the launched application.